# Puppet device wildcard names for nodes?

Tags: linux, centos, puppet, ruby, automation

I'm using Puppet's device management to mange some Cisco devices.

Right now my device.conf looks like this:

```
[someCity]
type cisco
url telnet://puppet:123456@10.123.1.1/

[someOtherCity]
type cisco
url telnet://puppet:123456@10.123.2.1/

[someOtherOtherCity]
type cisco
url telnet://puppet:123456@10.123.3.1/
```

All the routers will have the same special puppet user configured so credentials for all of them will be the same.

Can I use wildcards or import names/IPs from a file instead of having to have them all individually defined in device.conf?